# how to display generated message in the console in flutter ?

Tags: printing, flutter, android-mapview

hello I tried to extract longitude and latidude message printed in the console, I use map view plugin https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/map_view. when I tap on the map a printed longitude and latitude is generated in the console, the function use is:

Receive map touches

```
mapView.onMapTapped
     .listen((location) => print("Touched location $location"));
```

But I want to read the  longitude and latitude generated in the console to upload my variable and show the map with the new coordinate.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You mean longitude and latitude seperated from each other? Or just calling a function with that?

Comment: currently I know how to extrat long and lat from a string with regex, but in this case the message isn't a string, it's printed and I can't use the printed message as a variable. so first I tried to extract the printed message and after use the regex function to have two separated variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var longitude;
var latitude;

mapView.onMapTapped.listen((location) { 
    print("Touched location $location");
    // in a stateful widget
    setState(() {
        longitude = location.longitude;
        latitude = location.latitude;
    };
});
```

Then use it with the var `longitude`.

Where someFunction is the function that updates the map. (For updating the map you can use a [state](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/))

Next time read the [starting guide](https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/) before asking.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to do with this example, to be more simple to me, how can I just display $location  like   :   new Text("$location"),  ? currently If I did this , $location is undefined name. I think I miss a brick between the plugin and the widget to be connect

Comment: I added to the answer.

Comment: I have an error with   someFunction(location["longitude"], location["latitude"]);   the message is :"Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 2 found"  and "the operator [] isn't  defined for the class 'Location' I think the problem come that it's a package. other problem when I add the    longitude = location["longitude"]; in the statful widget , I have a message :" Undefined name 'location'.

Comment: The post was updated. This happened as `someFunction` is not a function in your code and was just to show you how it would work.